# Is it possible to pass an argument in command line for a user to choose to run Selenium headed or headless?

Tags: java, selenium, shell, command-line

I know how to run my Selenium tests headless but am needing to also have the option to run headed with the browser and gui. Right now I am passing '-headless' through command line instead of setting the firefoxOptions headless boolean to true in the Selenium code.

I am new to passing arguments through command line but I know how to loop through them. I am wondering if I can make '-headless' conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use some build tool like gradle or maven. This will allow you to pass properties with -D parameter, like so: `./gradlew clean test -Dparam=val -Dparam2=val2`. So you would be able to retrieve props in your code with `System.getProperties()` or `System.getPropery(prop)`.

It's also possible to use environment variables and retrieve them with `System.getEnv()` or `System.getEnv(varName)`. But I'd recommend using properties for this specific task.

So the idea is that you pass args to the job, retrieve them in your code and pass them to firefoxOptions before calling driver.

I would not recommend to prompt user to provide any information during the run, as this will not work in Continuous Integration process (CI).
You should choose whether headless param should be mandatory (you will have to pass parameters explicitly every time), or optional with some default value. For example if no param provided, tests would run in headless mode by default.

`./gradlew clean test -Dbrowser=firefox -Dheadless=true`

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, I see what you're saying, but need a little clarification.  Would the -D params be something a person running the test could pass in command line? I have a automation.sh file already with initial specifications.  So if they were to run the test, would it be something like ./automation -Dheadless = true??

Comment: If you have sh file, you would have to pass params to sh file first, and from there pass params to the gradle. OR you may write custom param for sh file, which can be a boolean flag, and inside sh file make a common IF statement that executes command with param headless or without
You can reference to 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

```
    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you want to run this test in headless mode?",null, dialogButton);
    
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
          // Saving code hereoptions
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        }
```

use Joptionplaneframe java swing frame work

This will open a promot,

If you don't want prompt then use scanner:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //  prompt for the user's name
        System.out.print("Enter yes or no: ");

        // get their input as a String
        String input= scanner.next();
        
        System.out.print(input);
```